# How should Apache IoTDB be started after changing the IP number setting of data node properties?

Tags: ip-address, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a question to ask about Apache IoTDB: I changed the 127.0.0.1 in iotdb-datanode.properties to my actual ip. However, when I tried to start IoTDB, an error occured. I checked the log of IoTDB, and the log prompts that "cannot register datanode with wrong id".

How can I change the ip number of IoTDB and start it successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.0, after you modified the ip and port number, that node needs to be formatted and restarted. You can try to delete the data directory and restart.

If you are not able to do that, you can just update IoTDB to Version 1.0.1 or Version 1.1.0, which this bug is already fixed.